# Why do I get a blank page when running my application from Netbeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, jstl

Yesterday everything was working just fine but today I'm running into this annoying blank page whenever I try to run my application from the IDE.

My server is `Glassfish/port4848` then run from the IDE `http://localhost:8080/ecommerce/`

The problem seems to be when I add these two library references at the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Sql statetments

```
<sql:query var="selectedCategory" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
    SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = ?

<sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}"/>
</sql:query>

<sql:query var="categoryProducts" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
    SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id = ?
    <sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}"/>
</sql:query>
```

When I remove the SQL statements from the top, the page loads perfectly fine when I request it in my local browser. Thing is I need the libraries to be able to run these JSTL:

Category page/ left column (vertical menu bar)

```
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categories.rows}">

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${category.id == pageContext.request.queryString}">
                <div class="categoryButton" id="selectedCategory">
                    <span class="categoryText">
                        ${category.name}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <a href="category?${category.id}" class="categoryButton">
                    <div class="categoryText">
                        ${category.name}
                    </div>
                </a>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
```

Displaying the product within the table (right column/products container)

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts.rows}" varStatus="iter">

    <tr class="${((iter.index % 2) == 0) ? 'lightBlue' : 'white'}">
        <td>
            <img src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.png"
                alt="${product.name}">
        </td>
        <td>
            ${product.name}
            <br>
            <span class="smallText">${product.description}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            &euro; ${product.price} / unit
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="addToCart" method="post">
                <input type="hidden"
                       name="productId"
                       value="${product.id}">
                <input type="submit"
                       value="add to cart">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>

</c:forEach>
```

I'd like to precise that I don't have the issue with my index page that also contains JSTL and the two references at the top. The problem is only with my category page.

Full Category Source Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

<%-- 
    Document   : category
    Created on : Feb 01, 2015, 7:56:19 PM
    Author     : PC
--%>


<sql:query var="categories" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
    SELECT * FROM category
</sql:query>

        <sql:query var="selectedCategory" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
    SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = ?
    <sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}"/>
</sql:query>

    <sql:query var="categoryProducts" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
    SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id = ?
    <sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}"/>
</sql:query>


<html>
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>Ecommerce | Online Shopping</title>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/category.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css"/>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0pt auto; padding: 0pt; max-width: 100%; width: 100%;">


        <div id="store_container">
<div id="store">
<div style="text-align: center;" id="category">
<div id="items">categories
</div>
<div class="cat_row">
<div style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);">Brand new
products</span><br>
</span><span style="font-weight: normal;"></span><span style="font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);">Items
on Sale</span><br>
<span style="text-decoration: underline;"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="cat_row">
<div style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Shop
by technology</span><br>
<br>
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categories.rows}">

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${category.id == pageContext.request.queryString}">
                <div class="categoryButton" id="selectedCategory">
                    <span class="categoryText">
                        ${category.name}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <a href="category?${category.id}" class="categoryButton">
                    <div class="categoryText">
                        ${category.name}
                    </div>
                </a>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

    </c:forEach>
<br>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cat_row">
</div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;" id="thumbnails">
<div id="items"> Featured Items | ${selectedCategory.rows[0].name}
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align: left;">
<div class="item_col">pages 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-10...<br>
</div>
<div style="text-align: left;" class="item_col2">24 per
page&nbsp;&nbsp; 48 per page&nbsp;&nbsp; 96 per page&nbsp;&nbsp; View
All<br>
</div>
</div>
<br>

<div id="thumb_container">
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}" varStatus="iter">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 275px;"><img src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.png"
                    alt="${product.name}"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 275px;"><img src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.png"
                    alt="${product.name}"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 275px;"><img src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.png"
                    alt="${product.name}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 275px;">${product.name}<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 275px;">${product.name}<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">${product.name}<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 275px;">&cad; ${product.price} / unit<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">&cad; ${product.price} / unit<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">&cad; ${product.price} / unit<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 275px;">
      <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 50%;"><form action="addToWishlist" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="productId"
                           value="${product.id}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Add To Wishlist">
                </form><br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><form action="addToCart" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="productId"
                           value="${product.id}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Add To Cart">
                </form><br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
      <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

          <tbody>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 50%;"><form action="addToWishlist" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="productId"
                           value="${product.id}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Add To Wishlist">
                </form><br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><form action="addToCart" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="productId"
                           value="${product.id}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Add To Cart">
                </form></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
      <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 50%;"><form action="addToWishlist" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="productId"
                           value="${product.id}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Add To Wishlist">
                </form><br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><form action="addToCart" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="productId"
                           value="${product.id}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Add To Cart">
                </form></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
         </c:forEach>
      </table>
      <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not JavaScript rather JSTL. On which server are you running your site? Maybe you are missing the jar-file. Are you using any JSPs at all? Or are you just using plain HTML and trying now to add some JavaScript?

Comment: @JoachimRohde: Thanks for replying. Right now i'm running my site on GlassFish LocalHost/4848. What jar-file are you talking about? Yes i'm using JSP. All my pages are JSPs.

Comment: Where is in your code the  start tag of `</c:forEach>` ? An where is your `<sql:setDataSource url=....` ?

Comment: In most cases, this is kind of behavior from an unsuccessful connection to the database server. It would be good if we could also see the `sql` statement.

Comment: @moskito-x: I added the sql statements and everything else. As for the connection to the database server, I tested everything and it works fine. All the other pages load perfectly fine when I request them in my local host browser.

Comment: Last not least the `<sql:setDataSource var=...` part :-)

Comment: @moskito-x: better late than never loll!

Comment: @moskito-x: Strange... the `</c:forEach>` is gone you're right... But that problem doesn"t occur in the IDE... It must be here... As for the `<sql:setDataSource var=...` Which part is missing? Because this is all the code I have... :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display a page correctly is not related to the **taglib** .

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
```

Mostly is a false **select statement** the reason.

Your code does not match the variables !
So a `<c:forEach` with a `rowcount == 0` will never run and your page is blank.

- query var="selectedCategory" is never used.
- `${pageContext.request.queryString}` is never tested.

---

Test `${pageContext.request.queryString}` with : [look here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSTL/JSTLPrintPageContext.htm)

---

```
<sql:query var="selectedCategory" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
    SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = ?

<sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}"/>
</sql:query>
```

- `<c:forEach` uses `${categories.rows}` ! where it come from ?

---

```
 <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories.rows}">
```

Replace `param value="a valid ID"` with a known value .

```
<sql:query var="selectedCategory" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
        SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = ?      
<sql:param value="a valid ID"/>
</sql:query>

<c:forEach var="category" items="${selectedCategory.rows}">
      <div class="categoryButton" id="selectedCategory">
           <span class="categoryText">
            ${category.name}
           </span>
      </div>
</c:forEach>
```

---

Also `items="${products}"` is not matching any sql query.

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}" varStatus="iter">
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a possible solution. To be honest with you, I have a hard time understanding your explanation... The code I have comes from the Netbeans ecommerce tutorial, you can easily check on their site for it. If you do, check the sixth point "working with JSTL".

Comment: @user23524697 : If you named your query `<sql:query var="selectedCategory"` you must use it ! You call it with `items="${categories.rows}">` and that's wrong. `selectedCategory` versus `categories`.

Comment: Okay I get you. Sorry I was a bit lost. So `selectedCategory` is in my code, I just forgot to paste it here. It is to display the selected category in the products container once clicked. I use this statement `${selectedCategory.rows[0].name}`. I will paste the whole code for you so you can see it.

Comment: Check the full code please. Thanks for your patience and your help! Really appreciate that!

Comment: also I forgot to mention, say I call the `index page` from my browser: `http://localhost:8080/ecommerce/index.jsp` Everything works fine. I get blank pages whenever I click on a category. Say I click on category `Computers`, well my browser displays the correct link like this `http://localhost:8080/ecommerce/category?2` but the whole page is entirely blank. Everything related with the `category page` just return straight blank.

Comment: @user23524697 : that's why I told you : Test the `${pageContext.request.queryString}` OR for test hardcode your `<sql:param value="2"/>` . Create a new file with only a few lines to test only `SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = ?` . For us your code is to much to read. (much possible errors).

Comment: I just tested your solution by replacing with a known value. Still return blank every time.. :S

Comment: Ok I think you are right. I just removed the `SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = ?` from the page and `http://localhost:8080/ecommerce/category` and everything related to `category` is loading fine now. I think we're getting closer to finding a solution. Thanks for your patience mate.

Comment: @user23524697 : What you get with `SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = 2` without `<sql:param` ?

Comment: I just tested by removing the third sql tastement `<sql:query var="categoryProducts" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
    SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id = ?
    <sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}"/>
</sql:query>` and it works fine. When I put it back it returns blank.

Comment: I think the third sql statement `<sql:query var="categoryProducts"`  is the issue...

Comment: @user23524697 Please create a new file to test with only a few lines. without excessive use of css and html . Also `<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}"` is not matching any `sql query`.

Comment: You want me to test with all the statements or only with one in particular?

Comment: Can you please see `Working with JSTL` here: [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/connect-db.html)

Comment: @user23524697 : have you replaced , in the code `items="${products}"` with `items="${categoryProducts}"` . Is useless to guess if there are such errors. Why not make a simple file with all your query and only text output, to see what's going on ????

Comment: Yes. I will create a file and get back to you tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Mate! I cant thank you enough for your patience! You know i've only be self-teaching myself to program for few months so sometimes I don't get it right away! But at least I try! I made some tests yesterday. The results:
Instead of running the whole app, I decided to try run file `category` alone for the 100th time. When I put all `3 query statements` and run file `category` from Netbeans, Glassfish returns a 500 Error: `javax.servlet.ServletException: SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id = ^ :Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: So of course it was wrong... it was the wrong table. It wasnt `product` but `category_has_product` since it's a many:many relationship instead of 1:1. The category pages no longer return blank when I call them from the browser. For the `<<c:forEach var="product"` , i dont know how they got replaced! Must of been a bug cuz I never did it! Strange! But now I've replaced everything and everything works fine now dude! Cheers! :D

Comment: @user23524697 : And now can you check my answer as right ? Much time spending !